# Fixing local orthorectification mismatches leading to small georeferencing errors?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, imagery, orthorectification

My project uses good quality high resolution orthorectified imagery (from the government) as its reference base layer. I complement it for vegetation analysis with additional imagery from a different source, also orthorectified.

The georeferencing is pretty good overall, but there are local "registration differences" between the two in some places. They probably arise from different orthorectification algorithms and assumed DEMs used by the 2 vendors. See example below; the polygons are digitized pine trees from the reference leaf-off imagery that I consider "ground truth". The overlaid leaf-on imagery from the other source is misaligned by about 4 metres *in this location*.

[image: Misalignment example]

What's the best approach to fix this, and **workflow to ideally do it dynamically**, in QGIS or compatible tools (e.g. GDAL, grass, other plugins)?

By "dynamically" I mean the following. I can of course re-georeference the supplemental imagery throughout my broad ROI, using a large number of GCPs and the thin plate spline method (which operates by local deformations). But this seems to be intended as a one-off, where I do it well once, and then use the modified (deformed) re-georeferenced image as my layer. It can be re-done at some point in the future with modified GCPs, but it's a hassle and time-consuming when the overall ROI/image is large.

What I'd love is a more "on the fly" version, where I can zoom into an area that becomes of interest (like the pic attached), fix up the errors there when I need to, and have QGIS (or whatever) "locally deform on the fly" just like it reprojects CRSes on the fly. I might later do the same in some other area of the image. I expect thin plate spline would likely be the algorithm under the hood, but I'm open to anything that works (piecewise affine likely good enough).

Comment: just a wild guess, but using custom 'grid shift' files modelled after [NTv2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=ntv2) might work. Qgis also has some [rubber-sheet plugins](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tags/rubber-sheet/) that might leveraged.